# Why we need $\sigma$ finite measure to define $L^{p}$ space?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am curious why we need $\sigma$ finite measure to define $L^{p}$ space. More generally, Why we need $\sigma$ finite measure instead of just finite measure?

Comment: Some classical $L^p$'s are $L^p(\mathbb R)$ and $L^p([0,1])$

Comment: Every finite measure is also $\sigma$-finite, but not the other way around (e.g., the usual measure on $\mathbb{R}$).  Are you asking why it is possible to define $L^p$ on $\sigma$-finite measures?

Comment: Universalset, Yes that's exactly I am asking

Answer (score 2):

You can define $L^p$ on any measure space you like.  If it just those measurable functions for which $|f|^p$ is integrable.  And then you modulo by functions zero a.e.

But if you don't impose some hypothesis like $\sigma$ finite, many results about $L^p(\mathbb R)$ don't always generalize very well to arbitrary measure spaces.